# Evaluate nil values from gomobile bind

Tags: android, go, mobile, gomobile

What's the right way to evaluate **nil** returned values from **Go** functions in Android Java?

Here's what I've tried:

```
// ExportedGoFunction returns a pointer to a GoStruct or nil in case of fail
func ExportedGoFunction() *GoStruct {
  return nil
}
```

Then I generate a .aar file via gomobile using:

`gomobile bind -v --target=android`

In my Java code I tried to evaluate **nil** as **null** but it's not working. Java Code:

```
GoLibrary.GoStruct goStruct = GoLibrary.ExportedGoFunction();
if (goStruct != null) {
   // This block should not be executed, but it is
   Log.d("GoLog", "goStruct is not null");
}
```

Disclaimer: Other methods from the go library work flawless

Comment: Go's `nil` is a typed value, so I don't think it translates directly to Java's `null`.  You might need to check it against the zero value of `GoStruct`.

Comment: Yes, I tried that and then the app crashed mumbling something about improper pointer de-reference. BTW, if a struct is nil in go and you try to access it's fields, go also crashes, so testing GoStruct for Zero values is (literally) a no go for Java

Comment: Hmmm, I was afraid that would happen.  I'm not sure how the bind is casting nil.  A really hacky solution would be a try/catch block to test for nil by forcing the exception.  And, yes I do feel dirty even suggesting it.

Comment: Actually that's what I came up doing. And then I wrapped all my code in yet another class to handle all my go functions just to avoid try/catch blocks, causing yet more overhead. I guess the folks at gomobile should have a very good reason to not map nil to null, I'm just failing to see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For possible future reference, as of **09/2015** I've come up with two ways of dealing with the problem.

The first one is to return an error from the **Go** code and **try/catch-ing** the error in **Java**. Here's an example:

```
// ExportedGoFunction returns a pointer to a GoStruct or nil in case of fail
func ExportedGoFunction() (*GoStruct, error) {
   result := myUnexportedGoStruct()
   if result == nil {
      return nil, errors.New("Error: GoStruct is Nil")
   }

   return result, nil
}
```

And then try/catch the error in **Java**

```
try {
   GoLibrary.GoStruct myStruct = GoLibrary.ExportedGoFunction();
} 
catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace(); // myStruct is nil   
}
```

This approach is both idiomatic **Go** and **Java**, but even if it works on preventing the program to crash, it ends up bloating the code with try/catch statements and causing yet more overhead.

So, based on user [@SnoProblem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4638952/snoproblem) answers the non-idiomatic way of solving it and properly handle null values I came up with was:

```
// NullGoStruct returns false if value is nil or true otherwise
func NullGoStruct(value *GoStruct) bool {
    return (value == nil) 
}
```

And then check the code in **Java** like:

```
GoLibrary.GoStruct value = GoLibrary.ExportedGoFunction();
if (GoLibrary.NullGoStruct(value)) {
   // This block is executed only if value has nil value in Go
   Log.d("GoLog", "value is null");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the testing package for go mobile, it looks like you need to cast the null value to the type.

From the SeqTest.java file:

```
 public void testNilErr() throws Exception {
    Testpkg.Err(null); // returns nil, no exception
  }
```

Edit:  A non-exception example, too:

```
byte[] got = Testpkg.BytesAppend(null, null);
assertEquals("Bytes(null+null) should match", (byte[])null, got);
got = Testpkg.BytesAppend(new byte[0], new byte[0]);
assertEquals("Bytes(empty+empty) should match", (byte[])null, got);
```

It may be as simple as:

```
GoLibrary.GoStruct goStruct = GoLibrary.ExportedGoFunction();
if (goStruct != (GoLibrary.GoStruct)null) {
   // This block should not be executed, but it is
   Log.d("GoLog", "goStruct is not null");
}
```

EDIT:  Suggestion for utility method:

You could add a utility function to the library to give you the typed `nil` value.

```
func NullVal() *GoStruct {
    return nil
}
```

Still a bit hacky, but it should be less overhead than multiple wrappers and exception handling.

Comment: I upvoted the question but somehow it doesn't work. I guess I'll have to keep try/catch -ing nil values.

Comment: You could add a function `GoLibrary.NullVal()` that returns a typed `nil` value.

Comment: There's no way to have a Struct as a return type when generating a .aar file via gomobile bind. Pointers to struct however work. That's why I'm returning a pointer to my GoStruct in my ExportedGoFunction(). Also, by using NullVal()  I would end with something that's not idiomatic Go nor idiomatic Java and lose the flexibility of pointers.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that to return a pointer rather than a struct.  I'll fix that in the code.  I don't mean to suggest that this is idiomatic in either language, but it's likely a more efficient alternative to wrappers and exception handling.